# SQL Find depth of child row relative to top parent row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a a CTE that returns parent child relationships. If I select a where clause using PanelID i get all parents of the child panel. However, the depth is in reverse. I need the dept of the child panel to be 2 and the top parent to be 0.

```
WITH category_cte AS 
(SELECT PanelID AS SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, 0 AS depth FROM dbo.tblPanels
                     UNION ALL
 SELECT CTE.SourceID, C.PanelID, C.BP_DP, CTE.depth + 1 AS depth
            FROM dbo.tblPanels AS C INNER JOIN
               category_cte AS CTE ON C.SCID = CTE.PanelID)
        SELECT        SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, depth
         FROM            category_cte AS category_cte_1 where PanelID = x
```

Return

```
SourceID    PanelID BP_DP   depth
1240         1240     1       0
1446         1240     1       1
1434         1240     1       2
```

Comment: Isn't that what's being returned?  Using a CTE recursively with a calculated depth should return the top node as 0 and subsequent nodes as > 0.  So, if we have grandparent-parent-child it comes out 0-1-2.

Comment: The return gives the value as 0 for the child. I was looking for the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to wrap your query in a subquery and use `ROW_NUMBER` to compute the `depth` in descending order:

```
WITH category_cte AS 
(SELECT PanelID AS SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, 0 AS depth 
 FROM dbo.tblPanels

 UNION ALL

 SELECT CTE.SourceID, C.PanelID, C.BP_DP, CTE.depth + 1 AS depth
 FROM dbo.tblPanels AS C 
 INNER JOIN category_cte AS CTE ON C.SCID = CTE.PanelID)    
SELECT SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY depth DESC) -1 AS depth
FROM (
  SELECT SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, depth
  FROM category_cte AS category_cte_1 
  where PanelID = x) AS t
```